# A property of homogeneous of degree p functions:

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, homogeneous-equation

Prove that if $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ is homogeneous of degree $p$, i.e; $f(tx)=t^pf(x)$. Then:

$$(x_1 \frac { \partial}{\partial x_1} +...+x_n \frac { \partial}{\partial x_n})^mf(x_1,...,x_n)=p(p-1)(p-2)...(p-m+1)f(x_1,...,x_n)$$

I've tried using the multinomial theorem and doing some induction over $m$, however I haven't been able to prove it even for $m=2$. Is this approach right, or what would you do?

Comment: Differentiate with respect to $t$, set $t=1$ at the end.

Comment: For $m=1$, this is just Euler's theorem i.e. $(\vec{x}\cdot\nabla)f(\vec{x})=p f(\vec{x})$ if $f(t\vec{x})=t^p f(\vec{x})$. But I don't see how it can be right for $m>2$, since it should just amount to two applications of Euler's theorem to get $p^2$ not $p(p-1)$. The he case of $f(\vec{x})=\vec{x}$ seems an obvious counterexample. (If it were $p(p-1)$, then the first application of the operator $\vec{x}\cdot\nabla$ would have to produce a homogeneous function of degree $p-1$.)

Answer (score 0):

Be $y=tx$. Then on one hand, you have
$$\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} f(y)\right|_{t=1} = \left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} f(tx)\right|_{t=1}
= \left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} t^p f(x)\right|_{t=1} = \left.\vphantom{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}} p t^{p-1} f(x)\right|_{t=1} = p f(x)$$
On the other hand, you have
$$\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} f(y)\right|_{t=1} = \left.\left(\frac{\mathrm dy_1}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1} + \ldots + \frac{\mathrm dy_n}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_n}\right)f(y_1,\ldots,y_n)\right|_{t=1} = \left(x_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \ldots + x_n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\right)f(x)$$

It should be obvious how to extend that for higher derivatives.

Comment: The thing is when you extend it to higher derivatives you have to deal with a multinomial term that is not-so-simple, at least I haven't been able to prove it for a general value of $m$

Comment: No, you haven't. Note that you're actually *calculating* the $n$-th derivative only in the first equation (where there's only a polynomial in $t$). In the second equation, you just use $d/dt = \sum dy/dt \partial/\partial y$ repeatedly, and *don't* try to calculate anything. (note $(d/dt)^n f = d/dt (d/dt)^{n-1} f$; now $(d/dt)^{n-1} f$ is a function, just like $f$ is; note that $f$ itself is left alone, and only $d/dt$ is rewritten in the second equation)