# If $f$ is homogeneous of degree $n$, set $p = xt$ and $q = yt$ and define $h(x,y,t) = f(p,q) = t^nf(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

A function $f$:$\mathbb R$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb R$  is called homogeneous of degree n if it satisfies $f(tx,ty) = t^nf(x,y)$

If $f$ is homogeneous of degree $n$, set $p = xt$ and $q = yt$ and define
$h(x,y,t) = f(p,q) = t^nf(x,y)$
Apply the chain rule to $h(x,y,t)$ to show that

> $x\frac {\partial {f}}{dx} + y\frac {\partial {f}}{dy} = nf(x,y)$

I don't know how to start, usually with homogeneous equation I substitute x and y with tx and ty and gives me this  $f(tx,ty) = t^nf(x,y)$ form with degree. I'm not quite sure how to tackle this question.

Comment: See: [Verify for $f(x,y)$, homogeneous of degree $n$: $xf_x+yf_y=nf$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130451/verify-for-fx-y-homogeneous-of-degree-n-xf-xyf-y-nf) ; [A property of homogeneous of degree p functions:](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956209/a-property-of-homogeneous-of-degree-p-functions)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, Let me know if I'm right

$h(x,y,t) = f(p,q) = t^nf(x,y)$

$f(xt,yt) = t^nf(x,y)$ we were given If $f$ is homogeneous of degree $n$, set $p = xt$ and $q = yt$

Now take the partial derivative on L.H.S and full derivative on R.H.S

$xt\frac {\partial {f}}{dxt} + yt\frac {\partial {f}}{dyt} = nt^{n-1}f(x,y)$

Now set $t = 1$

$x\frac {\partial {f}}{dx} + y\frac {\partial {f}}{dy} = nf(x,y)$